# Opening a specified folder in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Hello can anyone tell me how can I open a specified folder in Qt?

Suppose in a lineEdit I define the folder path like

```
D:/MyFolder
```

Then how can i open this folder using push button?
What should I use for that?

Comment: Do you mean opening a folder in the file explorer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(yourFolderPath));
```

inside a slot connected to you button.